# Simple SSIS package for Delta change - SSIS 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis

We have a client requirement to copy data/rows from Oracle Database(Live feed) to SQL Database on daily basis.

Source database tables contains around 11 million rows at average on each table and some tables contain Modified date field which has trigger on it.

How do I create a package to copy all the rows to SQL Table which takes less time?

Currently I have created a package [using modified date field as the main one] using slowly changing dimension transformation but this scan all the data in source table thus taking more time,
Is there a way to scan the table fast and load only new/updated records?

Comment: I would create linked server from SQL to Oracle and then on sql side select all data from oracle via the link and store them in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Merge script in this case which is faster then SCD(Slow and changing Dimention) for heavy data migration. Call a stored procedure from SSIS and Merge the data into destination which is updated or inserted in the source.

Comment: Could you please give me a rough image of it like how it looks after creating package because I tried to do this but not successful may be i'm doing wrong somewhere...